# How to specify default encryption for s3 bucket using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is it possible to set default kms encryption for s3 bucket using aws cli?

Comment: Is it acceptable to set default encryption directly on the bucket instead of from the CLI? See [Amazon S3 Default Encryption for S3 Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/bucket-encryption.html) for how to configure default as KMS. Also, are you asking how to set the default on the bucket, or how to default to KMS when doing cp, sync, etc? If so, look at [put-bucket-encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-encryption.html).

Comment: Note that it is in `s3api`, not in `s3`. So you'll need to use `aws s3api put-bucket-encryption`.

Comment: @dmulter is this the sintax?
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket td-extfs-cli-test --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules":[..]}'

Comment: Looks about right, try it and see!

Answer (score 0):

For AES256:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket bucketname --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}
```

For KMS:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket bucketname --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "aws:kms","KMSMasterKeyID": "kmskeyID"}}]}
```